# Not getting Confirmation code while trying to confirm emails using Identity methods. ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When i try to send confirmation email to user and then click provided link, i get current userId but not "code" like token or something, here is the classes:

**ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RandApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

There is the method which sends callBackUrl from which this method(mentioned above) should take the "code" but it doesn't.

**Email.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSendVerificationEmailAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await LoadAsync(user);
                return Page();
            }

            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                email,
                "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account {HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}");

            StatusMessage = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
```

So what can be the problem or where this "userId" (parameter of OnGetAsync method) even come from, i mean if i get userId, what is wrong with "code" parameter?

Comment: How are you getting the code? Does your `callBackURL` returning the required information as response?

Comment: That is my question too :D. as i guess, OnPostSendVerificationEmailAsync method, in callbackurl there is "value" field and there is object with area, userId and code parameters. i think this should provide OnGetAsync method with userId and code but for some reason it doesn't. i am just making assumptions, i dont know exactly. that is why i asked that qustion to find out the real reason

Comment: when i check with debugger, callbackurl does contain code and userId and everything works fine, but not getting value in other method

Comment: I think you should pass your code in this method `await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);` in your identity imlementation

Comment: it is already passed, isnt it?

Comment: Yes you have passed it in diffrent way, so you could have a try this way.

Comment: it doesn't matter because OnGetAsync() doesn't get code parameters value, it is null and i am trying to figure it out why is it null

Comment: figured it finally. it was the problem of encoding "code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));" i remove them and now it works fine but was it best way to deal with it?

Comment: You don't need to `encode` it manually, the value is already encoded with `hash-value` so when identity endpoint would receive it will decode the hash value, but when you have encode it manually no longer it can decode, as the result you are not getting the confirmation. All the process managed itself by `identity` no manual intervantion required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was encoding of this "code". after I remove them from methods it works fine, but was it the best way to remove them? because if it wasn't needed to be in the method, it wouldn't be.